# SQL user defined function, with table variables as input & return value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, table-variable

I have a user defined table-valued function that has an input type of a table variable, and the return type is another table variable.

However, when I try to execute the function it throws the error "Must declare the scalar variable". It looks like the call to the function does not have knowledge of the table variable @myTable, even though it is declared on the previous line.

I think I'm going crazy... can you spot what I am doing wrong?

```
-- Create the table type
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableType] AS TABLE(
    [z] [varchar](50) NULL
)
GO


-- Create the user defined function
USE [databaseName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[boxPackingSort3](@TableName TableType READONLY)
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE(
    [partno] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Q] [int] NULL,
    [L] [int] NULL,
    [W] [int] NULL,
    [H] [int] NULL,
    [Id] [int] NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable SELECT 'xxx', '1' , '1', '1', '1', '1' 
    RETURN
END


-- Call the user defined function
DECLARE @myTable TableType
INSERT INTO @myTable(z) VALUES('aaa')
select * from  dbo.[boxPackingSort3](@myTable)



Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Must declare the scalar variable "@myTable".
```

Comment: works for me, only had to change `LocationName` to `z`

Comment: Well spotted - I just fixed the `LocationName` in my original post. I just tried getting a colleague to run this SQL and he had the same error message. We're running SQL 2008 R2, could that have any effect?

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't work. unless you are running the `select * from  dbo.[boxPackingSort3](@myTable)` in isolation, which I'm sure you are not doing right?

Comment: After a lot of testing, it turns out the problem was due to the database comparability being set to SQL Server 2000 (80). As soon as I changed it to SQL Server 2005 (80), the query started working. I think it's time to start reading up on SQL Upgrade Advisor....

Comment: @Brain101, can you post as an answer instead of comment to question. This will help others.